# Logic between rounding decimals to 2 digits c++

Tags: c++, decimal

I recently came across the following piece of code to display 2 decimal digits.

```
val = ((int)(val*100.0))/100.0
```

The result was as told, but I don't get the logic behind the functioning of it. Can anyone please explain.
Thank you.

Comment: Is this the exact code? I'd expect a cast to integral type between the multiplication and division.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't more like `val = round(val*100)/100`? The code you've posted will leave the value (more or less) unchanged, unless it overflows.

Comment: You are using float constants everywhere, so I don't see how this would accomplish anything.

Comment: This isn't rounding anything. And unless a non-float conversion is in the original code, it is hardly *doing* anything. If there is such a conversion, both answers below accurately describe what is happening (but is isn't *rounding*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the actual code looked something like this:

```
float val = 3.141592654;
val = ((int)(val * 100.0)) / 100.0; // result would be 3.14
```

Then the logic behind it is that the cast to an integer truncates the decimal.  So multiplying by 10^n (where n is the number of digits you want in the decimal) and then casting it would move the decimal to the right n places, and then drop the remaining decimal.  Then, you cast it back to a float and divide by 10^n to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing some essential details of the code - i do not think this code displayed by you would do anything, especially not rounding. Seems like this code is attempting to just truncate everything after the second digit.

Assuming it is a float datatype, the following is what you are looking for (for truncating).
I splitted it up for (more) simplicity:

```
float val = 42.1234;
int helpVal = val *100;       //produces 4212, the rest will simply be cut off
float roundedVal = helpVal/100.0;  //produces 42.12
```

To make it shorter you could also go with:

```
float val = 42.1234;
float roundedVal = ((int) (val*100))/100.0;
```

Comment: For the OP's info, this will *truncate*, not *round*, to the last two digits. Try it with 42.9876, which should *round* to 42.99. The description is accurate. nice (+1)

Comment: Well, my fault. Was responding to the question text (which says nothing about rounding) but somehow managed to ignore the title...

Comment: Your answer is accurate (and in fact your comment "...will simply be cut off..." is correct). That was for the OP's benefit, not yours. I up-voted your answer. (poor choice of variable names, heh, but the description of the *algorithm* is good).